# How can I trace/reduce "PINNED" allocations?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to figure out how to trace where/why the PINNED section is growing as displayed below. I'm assuming there is something permanently holding onto references but don't know how to go about affecting this?

[image: RTS Output]

Comment: Well this may or may not be helpful, but the PINNED data is most likely (the underlying storage of) ByteStrings.

Comment: @ReidBarton Interesting. The program is processing a file using ByteStrings. Are you aware of any way to confirm where the allocations are originating, or any ideas regarding how to allow/force deallocations of the instances?

Comment: I usually start by trying all the different `-hX` options. Probably you will see a large component in each one and can get different kinds of information about where those allocations are coming from.